# Db query to return records where condition1=true alone or condition2=true alone, but not when condition1 and condition2=true collectively

Tags: mysql

```
user | manager | permission
-------------------------
adam    john         1
adam    john         2
adam    john         4
dave    john         1
dave    john         2
dave    john         3
dave    john         4
ben     rick         3
ben     rick         4
ben     rick         5
ed      susan        2
ed      susan        3
carl    susan        1
carl    susan        4
nancy   peter        3
nancy   peter        4
```

i want a query which would return user's having permission 2 but not 3 OR having permission 3 but not 2 BUT i DONT want users who have both permissions 2 and 3 and users who dont have both permissions 2 and 3

```
user
----- 
adam 
ben
nancy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you filter for who have permission 2 or 3 you can group and filter for who only have one permission in 2,3

```
SELECT
    user
FROM table
WHERE permission IN (2, 3)
GROUP BY USER
HAVING COUNT(permission) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `group by user` and check so that the max and min permissions are equal to either 2 or 3:

```
select user from tablename
where permission in (2,3)
group by user
having 
  (min(permission) = 2 and max(permission) = 2)
  or
  (min(permission) = 3 and max(permission) = 3)
```